# slick slider won't always load first time

Tags: slider, slick.js

i have an active site with 3 slick sliders on one page, usually the slick doesn't initialise and instead i just see all the images, sometimes if i refresh they all start working.

https://au.hairandme.com.au/collections/all/products/hair-rejuvenation-treatment

is the page in question.

```
 ( function($) {
$.noConflict();
  $(document).ready(function() { 
  $('.HEROSLIDE').slick({
    autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    pauseOnFocus: false,
  });

  $('.HEROSLIDEMOBILE').slick({
    autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    pauseOnFocus: false,
  });
    $('.benefits-slider').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        arrows: true,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: true,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: true,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});

$('.accordion').accordion({
defaultOpen: '',
cookieName: 'accordion_nav'
});
});
    } ) ( jQuery );
```

Comment: Still happens 2 years on...

Comment: This Slick Slider brought me a lot of problems for the last years. I apreciate it's free and there's people behind but it failed me too many times so I'm changing it for something else.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with 4 slick sliders on one page, the problem was the same, and it's the end of 2019 :)
but I fixed it with removing property 'adaptiveHeight', which this slider had. So, according to my problem, maybe you need also to check each property by comment on it

Answer (score 0):

For someone who still encounter this problem:

I've noticed that for my sliders this problem only occurs, when the number of slides is **less OR equal** than the number of slides in `slidesToShow` parameter in slick settings.

So, for example if my settings are:

```
$('.article_gallery_slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

than I have to have **at least 4** slides in order for them to appear correctly on first loading of a page.

For some sliders it doesn't really matter and I haven't had the time to investigate why, but I hope this info will help you with those sliders that work incorrectly